# HttpWebRequest WebClient Json Download 500 error

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, httpwebrequest

I have a list of urls (2900+) which enable me to download a Json object. I am attempting to loop through my list of urls and create a model in order to save aforementioned data to my database.

I have tried a couple of ways which both result in the same error:

**The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.**

The first method:

```
public string getJsonFromService(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        try
        {
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            WebResponse errorResponse = ex.Response;
            using (Stream responseStream = errorResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
                String errorText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                addBAGlog(errorText);
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The second method:

```
public string getJsonFromService(string url)
    {
        var client = new WebClient();
        var json= client.DownloadString(url);
        return json;
    }
```

The error seems to occur after around 10-20 records have been harvested.

I tried to delete break point urls in case they were bad urls, but on testing them singularly they work.

I have tried this in PHP and it works fine. All records are harvested in good time.

What is it in .net that is preventing me from accomplishing this?

Comment: I'm not sure if this solves your problem, but you should dispose the objects you are creating (the stream and reader on first method or the client on the second method).

Comment: It was my understanding that the @using will dispose automatically. I will try on the second method

Comment: You're right, I missed it. Did you tried also disposing `StreamReader` instances?

Comment: If `GetResponseStream` throws an exception, invoking it again on the `catch` block would throw again. Also the exceptions are been handled by the framework (MVC or WebApi) since you're thowing again on the `catch` block and on the second method you're not handling exceptions at all.